# Search for string and only display characters before it in Mapinfo label expressions

Tags: labeling, mapinfo, expression

So I have a property table that has addresses like below.

```
12 Andrews CL, Pxxx
1/12 Andrews CL, Pxxx
2/31 Macrossan ST, Pxxx
2/7-11 Barrier   ST, Pxxx
```

I need to only show

```
12
1/12
2/31
2/7-11
```

Can this be done within the expression builder in Mapinfo 12?

In python it would be something like address[:address.find(' ')]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using the Left$ and InStr functions as below. Check out the MapBasic Reference Guide (should be available in the Documentation folder of your MapInfo installation) for detailed information about those functions, along with a whole host of others.

```
Left$(address,InStr(1, address, " ") - 1)
```

Comment: You beat me to it by a few seconds, @T_Bacon :-)

Comment: So whose answer should I pick? you both answered the same but neither of them get all characters from the left up to the first space. Thanks for pointing me to the reference guide. I didn't know it was there.

Comment: Pick this one as he posted the answer seconds before me ;-)

Comment: No worries -but how do I get to print the first characters upto the first space?

Comment: @GeorgeC - The given code should work assuming that you have selected the correct field name and the space characters are in fact space characters. It seems like either the characters are not spaces (they could be tabs, carriage returns, line feeds, etc...) or you haven't used the correct field. I'd assume that you have the correct field so it is likely that the characters are not spaces. Try copying one of the fields values into Notepad++ (or some other decent text editor) and turning on the formatting characters. You should then be able to see what characters are used where the space is.

Comment: @GeorgeC - Or you could do it through MapBasic as Peter has suggested in the comments for his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Left$(ADDRESS, (InStr(1, ADDRESS, " ") - 1))
```

This will show the string to the left of the first space characters.
ADDRESS is here the name of the column

Comment: Thanks. It is printing Pxxx rather than 1/12. I want it to print from the first character upto the first space character.

Comment: Are you saying it's printing the characters from the right instead of the characters from the left?

Comment: Is the perceived space in fact a tab character by any chance? Try changing this bit: InStr(1, ADDRESS, " ") to InStr(1, ADDRESS, Chr$(9)), that might fix it.

Comment: So if the full address is "1/12 Davidson  ST, PORT SMITH" it is printing "Port" but it should print 1/12. How do I tell if it is a tab? it's all in one address field as {1/12 Davidson  ST, PORT SMITH}

Comment: With {Left$(Address, InStr(1, Address, Chr$(9))-1)} nothing prints.

Comment: Try this to figure out what character it is: select the object in the map and run these two statements via the MapBasic window which will print the ascii# of the character to the message window. The number 5 refers to the character you want to inspect: Fetch First From Selection Print Asc(Mid$(ADDRESS, 5, 1))